# Show compare attributes for every product

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
              <td class="align-middle">
            
              </td>
              @forelse($products as $product)
                <td>
                  <div class="comparison-item">
                    <a class="comparison-item-thumb" href="shop-single.html">
                      <img src="{{ Voyager::image($product->image) }}" alt="Apple iPhone X">
                    </a>
                    <a class="comparison-item-title" href="shop-single.html">{{ $product->title }}</a>
                  </div>
                </td>
                
              @empty

              Нет товаров для сравнения

              @endforelse
            </tr>

            @foreach($products as $keyp => $product)
            
                @foreach($product->prodChar as $key => $char)
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>{{ $char->prodCharacter->title }}</th>
                    <td>{{ $char->value }}</td>
                          
                    <td>-</td>
                    <td>-</td>
                
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            
            @endforeach
          
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block" href="#" data-toast data-toast-type="success" data-toast-position="topRight" data-toast-icon="icon-check-circle" data-toast-title="Product" data-toast-message="successfuly added to cart!">Add to Cart</a></td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block" href="#" data-toast data-toast-type="success" data-toast-position="topRight" data-toast-icon="icon-check-circle" data-toast-title="Product" data-toast-message="successfuly added to cart!">Add to Cart</a></td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block" href="#" data-toast data-toast-type="success" data-toast-position="topRight" data-toast-icon="icon-check-circle" data-toast-title="Product" data-toast-message="successfuly added to cart!">Add to Cart</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Image how this show:

[image: Click]

I need write: `"-"`. For product where attribute is none. Now I show all attributes in one column for every product. How I can fix this problem? I need compare keys of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're talking about this small section here:

```
           @foreach($product->prodChar as $key => $char)
            <tr>

                <th>{{ $char->prodCharacter->title }}</th>
                <td>{{ $char->value }}</td>

                <td>-</td>
                <td>-</td>

            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

So you have two options here:

**Option #1**: You could compare right in the view as follows:

```
<td>{{ $char->value?: "-" }}</td>
```

This would return a `-` whenever your value is null.

**Option #2**: You could create a mutator within the `ProductChar` model as follows:

```
 // ...your product model code
 public function getValueAttribute() {
  return $this->attributes['value']?: "-";
 }
```

This would make it so that when you call `$char->value` it will use the value (if not null) or return a `-` if it is null.